# Oracle dynamic table creation on runtime

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, search-engine, bulk-collect

I make to try a search engine.Scenario like that; I have a table that it contains text context and I'm fetching some records what suitable according to my query then I want to transfer this founded text of id on a table that created dynamicly on runtime. My sql code as follow but this error

```
"expression is of wrong type"
```

**SQL**

```
declare
  v_table dbms_sql.number_table;
begin
  select a_id bulk collect into v_table from (select a_id from b where length(b_data) > 4);

  select * from a where a_id in v_table;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DBMS_SQL.NUMBER_TABLE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_sql.htm#ARPLS68226) is an [associative array](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#LNPLS99969):

> Unlike a database table, an associative array:
>
> - Does not need disk space or network operations
> - Cannot be manipulated with DML statements

You can `select into` an associative array, but you cannot use it as a table in a `select`.

You could to the `select into` with a [nested table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#LNPLS99981) but you still couldn't use that in a `select` if the type is declared within your block because it would be a PL/SQL type that isn't valid within an SQL statement.

You would need a nested table type defined in SQL (i.e. not in PL/SQL) to achieve this. There is a built-in type to make it easier, but you can define your own:

```
declare
  v_table sys.odcinumberlist;
  v_table2 sys.odcinumberlist;
begin
  select a_id bulk collect into v_table
  from (select a_id from b where length(b_data) > 4);

  select a.a_id bulk collect into v_table2
  from table(v_table) vt
  join a on a.a_id = vt.column_value;
end;
/

anonymous block completed
```

The second `select` you showed is incomplete so I've made one up. Your first doesn't need the nested `select`, that can be simplified to:

```
  select a_id bulk collect into v_table
  from b
  where length(b_data) > 4;
```

Hopefully you're dong something with the collection before your second `select`, otherwise it's a bit pointless; you could just join `a` to `b` in the second `select` to get the same result:

```
  select a.<columns> ...
  from a
  join b on b.a_id = a.a_id
  where length(b.b_date) > 4;
```

Comment: Alex thanks , also i want to ask a question about bulk collect, how can i add multiple collection on bulk collect?Is there simple way for that reason?

Comment: @GoranZooferic - do you mean [something like this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e17126/tuning.htm#BABJCBGD)?